# Converting MySQL Timestamp to more readable format

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I'm looking to convert a Timestamp field from the: `2012-03-14 23:14:58` format to the (more readable) `23:14 pm March 15, 2012`

I've been through this [tutorial](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/10/05/how-to-convert-mysql-timestamp-to-php-date-type/), however I couldn't really get my head around it. I've included my current PHP script which I'm using to parse the MySQL database data to an Android application.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("*******", "*******", "*******");

if(!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("bluebase", $con);


$q=mysql_query("SELECT * from Comments where Category = 'General' ORDER BY Timestamp DESC");

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) 

        $output['General'][]=$e;

    print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
```

?>

Comment: 23:14 pm is redundant redundant.  wouldn't you want 11:14 pm?

Comment: You also can use MySQL DATE_FORMAT function - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: duplicate of [What is the simplest way to format a timestamp from SQL in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238071/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-format-a-timestamp-from-sql-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple paths you can take.  What I always do is store the time in the database as a Unix Timestamp, since it's simple to convert from there.  If you already have data in your database and it's too late to change it (or you have other reasons for having the date in that format in the database), then you'll need to convert your time into a unix timestamp so it's usable in the PHP date function:

```
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $e['Timestamp'] = date('h:i a F d, Y', strtotime($e['Timestamp']));
    $output['General'][]=$e;
}
```

... that overwrites the Timestamp field with your reformatted timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

This'll do the trick:

```
<?php
  echo date('H:i a F j, Y', strtotime($timestamp));
?>
```

Comment: your arguments are backwards, also the timestamp itself wouldn't work here.  You need to turn it into seconds first.

Comment: your function params are backwards.

Comment: You're right, I switched the arguments. Shame on me. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

`date('h:i a F d, Y', strtotime('2012-03-14 23:14:58'));`

Note that 'd' is date WITH LEADING ZEROS.

And 'h' is the 12 hour format since you want to display AM/PM

If you don't want leading zeros, use 'j' for the numeric day and 'g' for the 12 hour format hour number.

Comment: @SmilingBlue Check out Jason's answer.  He places it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format the date however you want.  Just use

```
date('H:i a F d, Y', strtotime($timestamp));
```

Though as Milo pointed out in the question comments, there's no reason to use 24 hour format AND am/pm.