# How can I format a timestamp from MySQL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

When I directly echoed a timestamp value I retrieved from a database in PHP, I saw this on my screen.

```
2012-04-01 12:02:00
```

What is an efficient way to parse this timestamp string in PHP? Should I use regex or explode to turn this timestamp into two strings and parse each one (date and time)?

Is there a more streamlined and standard way to do this?

In the end, I want to present this timestamp as: `12:02 on April 1, 2012`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the simplest way to format a timestamp from SQL in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238071/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-format-a-timestamp-from-sql-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
date('H:i on F d, Y',strtotime('2012-04-01 12:02:00'))
```

More info on date pattern here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

check out the [date()](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.date.php) and [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.strtotime.php) functions.

in your example it would be

```
date("H:i on F d, Y",strtotime("2012-04-01 12:02:00"));
```

and if you are using  a later PHP version than 5.3.0 you could use [date_parse_from_format](http://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.date-parse-from-format.php)() too. In this case:

```
$parsed = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s","2012-04-01 12:02:00");
$new = mktime(
        $parsed['hour'], 
        $parsed['minute'], 
        $parsed['second'], 
        $parsed['month'], 
        $parsed['day'], 
        $parsed['year']
);
date("H:i on F d, Y", $new);
```

Comment: `date() expects parameter 2 to be long, array given`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Silver89. I've fixed the second method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM times;");
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
       echo date("g:i a F j, Y ", strtotime($row["date"])) . "<br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner would be `date_create_from_format('H:i on F d, Y', $timestamp_value)`

More on this here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php